# Group by unique customers and then create column for min date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with customer IDs, transaction_date

Example of table:

```
ID    |transaction_date
PT2073|2015-02-28    
PT2073|2019-02-28    
PT2013|2015-04-28    
PT2013|2017-02-11   
PT2013|2017-07-11
```

GOAL: I want to create another column so that for each unique ID I get the first first transaction date. It should look like:

Example of table:

```
ID    |transaction_date|first_transaction_date
PT2073|2015-02-28    |2015-02-28 
PT2073|2019-02-28    |2015-02-28 
PT2013|2015-04-28    |2015-04-28
PT2013|2017-02-11    |2015-04-28
PT2013|2017-07-11    |2015-04-28
```

I created another table where I select the minimum and then group it :

`SELECT id, MIN(transaction_date) as first_transaction_date FROM customer_details GROUP BY id`

When I checked the table I was not getting the same value in `first_transaction_date` column for a unique id.

Answer (score 3):

Use `min()` as a *window function*:

```
select t.*, min(t.transaction_date) over (partition by t.id)
from t;
```

No `group by` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`first_value()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html): It gives out the first value of an ordered group (your groups are the `id`s that are ordered by the `transaction_date`):

[Click for demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=87bd142b74f7fd8b948fc4c6551eb318)

```
SELECT
    *,
    first_value(transaction_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY transaction_date)
FROM
    mytable
```

---

If your Postgres version does not support window functions (prior 8.4, Amazon Redshift):

[Click demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=41548b5a21c21c6671b127b94ba3d4bc)

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    (SELECT min(transaction_date) FROM mytable t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
FROM
    mytable t1
```

Comment: I am getting the error: Invalid operation: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause

Comment: See the demo link above. This is working. What did you change? Can you try to reproduce the problem with a fiddle?

Comment: Isn't that the same as `min(transaction_date) over (partition by id)` in this case?

Comment: I did not change anything. I am running it on sql workbench

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, of course ;) So, OP, try to reproduce the problem with the fiddle (show the real data and table structure an the code you used :)

Comment: @Py.rookie89: then you are not using Postgres. What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.11116

Comment: Postgres 8.0 doesn't support window functions

Comment: Added a solution without window functions

Comment: @Py.rookie89: that's the reason why you shouldn't tag questions for Amazon Redshift with Postgres